# Overlay an Image onto a video in windows 8 metro App using c#

Tags: c#, image, video, microsoft-metro, overlay

I'm trying to figure out how to overlay an image over a video file in windows 8 metro app using c#,i can found link http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowSamples/2010-February/ this is support only desktop application.Is there any way to solve my problem.please help any one.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XAML, you can easily add 2 overlapped controls, one on the background for the video and one for the image in the foreground. To make sure of the z-order, you can adjust the [Z-Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.zindex) of your controls.

With a transparent image control you should not have difficulty pulling this off.